# size and notnull spring anotation doesnt work properly

Tags: spring, eclipse-plugin, spring-annotations

@size @notnull annotation doesn't work, I double-check everything but still got no answer, I will upload my classes, I'm new to spring, by the way, hope you get what's wrong. (I use eclips for framework)

[this is my customer controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pusvc.png)

[this is my customer class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEapZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqHU.png)

thanks for your help and time.

this is my customer class:

```
public class Customer {
String firstName;


@NotNull
@Size(min=1,message="is required")
String lastName;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

and this is my customer controller class:

```
public class CustomerController {

@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm(Model model) {
     Customer thecustomer=new Customer();
     model.addAttribute("customer",thecustomer);
     //first one is name and the second one is value 
     return "customer-form";
}

@RequestMapping("/processForm")
 public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer")  Customer thecustomer,BindingResult theresult)
{
    if(theresult.hasErrors()) {
        return "customer-form";}
    else {
        return "customer-confirmation";}
    
}
```

and this is customer-form.jsp:

```html
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>customer registration</title>


<style > 

.error{color:red}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">
<p>firstname:</p> <form:input path="firstName"/>
<br>
<p>lastname:</p> <form:input path="lastName"/>
<form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you ever try to put them over each of your variables?

Comment: i try it now,it didnt work sadly

Comment: is there anyway i can connect with you anywhere else , i have so many questions about coding and nobody to help me with that :(

Comment: Hi, you should paste your code into the question with code formatting. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on writing you questions.

Comment: @HopeyOne hi thanks , i did it